# Symfony3 web debug toolbar shows up empty after upgrading from 2.8.16

Tags: symfony

I've just updated my Symfony application to version 3.2 from 2.8.16 and now the web profiler toolbar not showing up as expected.

<kbd>config_dev.yml</kbd>

```
    imports:
        - { resource: config.yml }

    framework:
        router:
            resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
            strict_requirements: true
        profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

    web_profiler:
        toolbar: true
        intercept_redirects: false
        position: top
```

Going to an automated error page (page not found error - 404) I can see the web debug toolbar completely empty:

[image]

The relative HTML code is the following:

```
    <div id="sfwdt9c958d" class="sf-toolbar sf-display-none" data-sfurl="/app_dev.php/_wdt/9c958d" style="display: block;"><!-- START of Symfony Web Debug Toolbar -->
        <div id="sfMiniToolbar-9c958d" class="sf-minitoolbar" data-no-turbolink="" style="display: none;">
            <a href="#" title="Show Symfony toolbar" tabindex="-1" id="sfToolbarMiniToggler-9c958d" accesskey="D">
                <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#AAAAAA" d=""></path>
    </svg>

            </a>
        </div>
        <style nonce="75799098050c6a6271f998e32cbdc849">
            /* Omitted */

        </style>
        <div id="sfToolbarClearer-9c958d" class="sf-toolbar-clearer" style="display: block;"></div>

    <div id="sfToolbarMainContent-9c958d" class="sf-toolbarreset clear-fix" data-no-turbolink="" style="display: block;">

                <a class="hide-button" id="sfToolbarHideButton-9c958d" title="Close Toolbar" tabindex="-1" accesskey="D">
                <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
    </svg>

            </a>
        </div>
    <!-- END of Symfony Web Debug Toolbar -->
    </div>
```

I've never seen this bug before. Maybe it is connected with a non-core package/bundle?

<kbd>composer.json</kbd>

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "twig/twig": "1.28",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "~3.3",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "^4.0",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "~6",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-php-connector": ">=2.5",
    "components/elfinder": ">=2.0",
    "leaseweb/doctrine-pdo-dblib": "^1.0",
    "symfony/finder": "^2.8",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "^2.1",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "^2.0",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master",
    "endroid/qrcode-bundle": "^1.6",
    "endroid/qrcode": "^1.6",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.0",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.2"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from [this well written upgrading guide](https://labs.kunstmaan.be/blog/how-to-upgrade-your-project-to-symfony-3) I've reviewed all the configuration steps.

Then I've analyzed the [default composer.json of Symfony v3.2.2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.2/composer.json#L21) and in particular the required twig version. I tried changing my Twig requirements  with:

```
"twig/twig": "~1.28|~2.0",
```

but sadly I'm using JMS translation bundle, which is not compatible with the latest Twig v2.1+ as [reported in this PR](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle/pull/426).

I found the solution removing the 2.0 requirement. So, to fix the issue I changed the Twig version requirement with `"twig/twig": "~1.28"` and the profiler bundle now seems to work as before.